# What are the primary architectural differences between the backup formats of some of the more common RDBMS' and what advantage do they serve?

Tags: sql-server, backup

Of the systems with which I am familiar, I have noticed that SQL Server's native database backup format is binary and proprietary. PostgreSQL and MySQL allow for a simpler approach, dumping the schemata and data. This leads to an interesting question.

> What are the primary architectural differences between the backup formats of some of the more common RDBMS' and what advantage do they serve?

It seems to me that the PostgreSQL and MySQL dump-style implementations would allow for one to open the backup in a text editor and get a sense for the data being restored.

Comment: Uhhhhh because.

Comment: Other "popular" - I agree the two you mentioned are popular. But Oracle, DB2, etc ;-) This is really just the way it is. It's how they've built their backup/restore engine and it has worked amazingly well so far. Many big, critical systems have been recovered alright. Not really sure about the benefits or downfalls of one approach over the other - It really is just what it is and what it's been. And it works. <shrug>

Comment: Perhaps if you gave some indication of *why you care* it might help narrow the set of potential answers to something manageable.

Comment: Also. Because the two that you have cited have no native differential/incremental backup functionality. And how would they of they're just dumping schemata and data?

Comment: I am voting to reopen. This is not an only-opinion-based-answers-possible questions as there are real technical differences that are important to know and understand when selecting your RDBMS and your backup strategy.

Comment: I'm leaving this closed since it likely to generate long winded discussion.  I still think if the OP wants to add details about what his specific concern is, then this is a valid question - as it is I don't see its value beyond what has already been said.

Comment: Postgres' "custom" format is actually better (more flexible) than the "plain SQL" format. Most people I know prefer that over the "plain SQL" format.

Comment: @SebastianMeine perhaps once the question is rephrased as such then i'd vote to reopen.

Comment: SQLite offers plain SQL export as well.

Answer (score 4):

The native backup of sql server, commonly have extension of `.bak` is something which is proprietary of microsoft.

Different RDBMS providers have different formats and it also depends on whether they are open source (PostgreSQL and MySQL) or are patented (MS SQL Server, ORACLE or SybaseASE).

For MS SQL Server :

A backup is a page-by-page copy of the database, as it existed the moment you took the backup, a restored copy of that database will be in exactly the same state as it was the moment you took the backup.

A backup contains more than just the data. It contains the entire structure of the database including all the data structures and data along with procedures, views, functions and any other code. It also contains the settings and definitions of the database along with the users of the database. Exception is `contained databases` have a concept called `USER WITH PASSWORD`.

If you want to use something that you mentioned, have a look at [SqlDump - Microsoft SQL Server database backup program](http://sqldump.sourceforge.net/)

> SqlDump is a program to backup a Microsoft SQL Server database as a text file. SqlDump generates SQL statements for tables, indexes, user-defined types, views, procedures, etc and also the table data. This data can be used for a variety of purposes, such as database backups, moving databases to another server, or setting up a test database based on the contents of an existing database

Note: I have not tried the SQLDump, as I would personally prefer SSIS or T-SQL along with BCP and BULK INSERT - to move data out and in of sql server.

Comment: Thanks for sharing SqlDump. It's antique now. The most recent version was published to [Sourceforce](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqldump/files/?source=navbar) in 2002! Phil Factor shows you how to make plain-text backups using [PowerShell SMO](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/automated-script-generation-with-powershell-and-smo/). You could use Red Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) together with less effort.

Comment: I don't want to replace the native backup system. I just wondered why it works differently from other popular RDBMS backup systems. You're on to something when you say "page-by-page copy". Could you expand on that? Does it contain pages for all indexes, or just the clustered ones?

Comment: @IainElder It contains entire structure of the database - clustered, non-clustered indexes, Foreign keys, Primary keys and many more as described in my answer.

Comment: @IainElder I am aware of those stuff and I did not mentioned it as it is a separate discussion - you can do a lot cool stuff with powershell and SMO.

Comment: @IainElder - the full backups take a page-by-page copy of the database *and enough log information to restore the database to a transactionally-consistent state at the time the file read (by the backup process) completes.* in this way it will also backup transactions that are committed during the backup phase. there is also the notion of a differential backup which will backup changed *extents* (which are groups of 8, 8k pages) which is determined by a special page that maps each extent to a bit on that special page. These differentials are based on a full backup base which allows for

Comment: the system to track which pages were changed on that base backup.

Comment: Full backups also include enough transaction log to guarantee consistency. If you do a table-by-table-to-raw-SQL backup, you can't guarantee consistency (foreign keys, reference constraints etc.).

Answer (score 3):

The biggest difference is transactional consistency.

To achieve a truly transactionally consistent backup using the generate-a-script method (aka dump method), you would have to stop all write access to all tables in the database. Otherwise, while you are scripting out records in one table, changes in another table might occur that would break defined or undefined (e.g. enforced by the app layer) relationships.

With a page by page backup as SQL Server is offering you might run into the same issue as well. However, SQL Server stores the log sequence number that the page was changed at last together with each page. That way that information makes it into the backup too. SQL Server stores also enough log information with each backup to  undo or redo transaction depending on their state at the time of the backup.

During a restore, first the data pages get copied from the backup to the new database file. Afterwards a redo/undo phase is executed to bring all pages into a consistent state using that additional log information that was stored within the backup.

So, when you use SQL Server you can run a true 24/7 operation and still take backups that are transactionally consistent.

There are also additional mechanisms like differential backups that backup only the data that changed since the last backup, or log backups, that can be used to restore a database to a particular point in time with sub-second precision (while still guaranteeing transactional consistency). All that would also not be possible with dump style backups.

Finally, dump style backups tend to take up a lot more space than native backups, but that probably could be mitigated through compression.

As for all the other stuff like procedures or permissions, that all could be scripted out too, so I do not think that those are a valid differentiator, but I do not know if postgres offers that option out of the box.

Comment: These also differ in reason for a restore. If you accidentally delete few rows from single table, then you might find feasible to restore a single table with different name. You can use plain text SQL format for this purpose, but not a binary format (except for Informix). On the other hand plain text SQL format can not be used for PITR(point in time recovery). When using plain text you can not specify `until time` - these backups can not be rolled forward to some point onto time axis.